# Would diagonally bracing studs on either side of a load bearing stud be safe to remove the load bearing stud?

Tags: studs

I presume not since I can't find much on it, but I'm curious on why if not.

Basically let's say we have three studs A,B, and C and we wish to remove the middle stud B. Could we run 45 degree braces from each side of Stud B to A and C? I presume one would need to brace the outer sides of A and C in the same way to equalize lateral forces; along with extra sistering studs on A and C.
Hopefully ascii art below helps.

```
________
\|/|\|/
 A B C
```

This of course would be augmented with a proper header but is meant to carry things while removing the stud avoiding the need for side support or jacks.

Comment: What are the studs supporting besides the ceiling? Another floor? Attic?

Comment: Do you want to remove the stud permanently, or is this temporary?

Comment: Maybe I didn't understand the question very well. I don't see how you can do this and also install a header. The studs would be in the way.

Comment: This looks like an [XY Problem](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem). What is that you're really trying to accomplish? It seems you've found a very creative solution, but odds are good that someone here has enough experience to solve the actual problem and the solution will probably be easier, simpler and safer than what you've come up with. i.e. there's probably a Very Good Reason™ you can't find any info on what you're attempting to do.

Answer (score 1):

No. Or yes. It depends on your risk tolerance.

Because the load applies vertically (gravity goes down) there would be both bending and sliding forces at play. Unless you accommodate that with appropriately stiff boards and adequate anchoring it's asking for trouble.

Instead, a conventional header is needed. Trimmer/jack studs along the remaining studs and a properly sized header between is the only good answer. It's also possible that you could use a "flush beam", which is basically a header integrated with the floor system so that it doesn't interfere with a full-height opening in the wall.

Maybe describe your project as a whole instead of asking such a specific question.

Answer (score 0):

Doing all this guesswork and adding fastener holes (i.e. *damage!*) to existing structure to "avoid" the side supports and jacks? Let's reiterate: you want to do more work to avoid doing less work, and you don't know enough if such a prolonged suffering is even structurally sound? **Don't**. Do it right. The side support columns can be reclaimed lumber (say 4x4 columns, or 2x6 box columns with good caps), and you can get bottle jacks for cheap from Harbor Freight. You most likely can find the lumber for free on Craigslist.